# How to set Isolation level in SpringData Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, transaction-isolation, kundera

Mongo allows us to set Isolation level e.g

```
db.foo.update(
    { status : "A" , $isolated : 1 },
    { $inc : { count : 1 } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

How can I set the same Isolation level through SpringData/Java Code?

Also is there any other way to achieve transactions? especially at the application code level? I looked at the Java driver that mongo provides and Spring Data but couldnt find any support(unless I am missing something) what about support from third party like kundera? zookeeper?

Comment: Did you find the solution ?